# Recursive method counting

Tags: c++

How does this recursive integer method count the number of nodes in a linked list? How can a constant 1 be added to a memory address?

```
int length(Node *head) {
  if(head == nullptr)
    return 0;

  return 1 + length(head->link);
}
```

Comment: 1 is not being added to an address here. It's being added to the value returned by a call to `length` which returns an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `length(head->link)` is a function call. The function being called, `length`, returns an `int`. So 1 is not being added to a pointer; it is being added to an integer.